# python2.7: check for string in a file and update a dict/list

Tags: list, python-2.7

What is the proper way to pattern match in structured data (in a file) and updating a list with it?  I run into issues with the list element value not being retained at the next elif condition (so it is as if they are not updated even if the previous condition matched and updated the list element).

e.g.

```
patterns1 = 'foo'
patterns2 = 'bar'
patterns3 = 'moo'

dict1 = {}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as textfile:

    for line in textfile:
        list1 = ["0","0"]
        if patterns1 in line:
            newline = line
            dict1[newline] = list1
        elif patterns2 in line:
            newline2 = line
            list1[0] = newline2
            dict1[newline] = list1
        elif patterns3 in line:
            newline3 = line
            list1[1] = newline3
            dict1[newline] = list1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `if` condition is satisfied, the `elif`s are bypassed the next iteration of the loop is started, try multiple `if`s:

```
for line in textfile:
    list1 = ["0","0"]
    if patterns1 in line:
        newline = line
        dict1[newline] = list1
    if patterns2 in line:
        newline2 = line
        list1[0] = newline2
        dict1[newline] = list1
    if patterns3 in line:
        newline3 = line
        list1[1] = newline3
        dict1[newline] = list1
```

This way, each condition will be tested instead of a cascade of passes